# Xamarin how to call a function using a button

Tags: android, sqlite, csv, xamarin, import

I have created a public class to import a csv file. No matter where I place the class in my code I cannot get it to run the function. I wish to click a button and have it run this code.

```
public class FileReader : Activity {
    // Create your application here
    public void OnCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Java.IO.FileReader file = new Java.IO.FileReader("AssetList.csv");
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(file);
        String line = "";
        String str1 = "INSERT INTO " + "Inventory" + " (TagNo,AssetDesc,Location,Category,AssetKey,SerialNo,Units,PISDate,Book,Supplier,SupplierNo,PONumber,Cost,ExpenseAcct,Status) values(";
                    String str2 = ");";

        db.BeginTransaction();
        while ((line = buffer.ReadLine()) != null) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str1);
            string[] str = line.Split(',');
            sb.Append("'" + str[0] + "',");
            sb.Append(str[1] + "',");
            sb.Append(str[2] + "',");
            sb.Append(str[3] + "'");
            sb.Append(str[4] + "'");
            sb.Append(str2);
            db.ExecSQL(sb.ToString());
        }

        db.SetTransactionSuccessful();
        db.EndTransaction();
    }
}
```

Comment: You've created a class which inherits from `Activity` class, why you do so? If you want to create a class, you can just put your code in the constructor of this class and in button click event, just "new" this class, you code would be called.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the delay. A few hours later I figured out your exact solution and it worked.